# Modify Max number of Query Execution at same time on monetdb

Tags: monetdb

Currently, I am using MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v11.43.21 (Jan2022-SP4)

Issue:
we are running more then 100 query concurrently by user in Monetdb  and sys.queue in Monetdb is showing 50 tuples only at a same time.

is there any setting by which i can modify execution /firing limit on Monetdb so that it can execute at least 80-90 query or more at a same time without timeout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `nclients` parameter to 100:

```
monetdb set nclients=100 <db>
```